# Infer the article from a situation

Tags: articles

Suppose I gave somebody one tie, then I can say

> He's wearing **the tie** I gave him.

But which article do I have to use if I gave somebody several ties?

> He's wearing **the tie** I gave him.

or

> He's wearing **a tie** I gave him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person (hopefully) is wearing *one tie!* So, you say:

> He's wearing ***the tie*** I gave him.

In this case, you gave him only *one* tie.

Now, you gave him more than one tie. But he is *wearing only one of them!*

Say,

> He's wearing ***one of the ties*** I gave him.

If he's weird and wearing many of them, you say:

> He's wearing ***the ties*** I gave him.

You are *specific* to talk about **the tie** that you gave. So, it's the definite article.

If you haven't gave him any, and he's wearing one...

> He's wearing ***a tie.***

You are not specific about it; he's wearing *some* tie, *any* tie.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that if I gave him 2 ties, then neither of phrases (neither "He's wearing the tie I gave him" nor "He's wearing a tie I gave him.") is correct? And the most correct and natural phrase is "He's wearing one of the ties I gave him." ?

Comment: That's correct. It wouldn't be *wrong* to say "... a tie...", but the most common and natural *is* "... one of the...".

Comment: @DimanNe Though if you said "He's wearing the tie I gave him", it's not even technically wrong.  It is the tie you gave him.  There just happen to be others as well.  It's implied you gave only one tie by saying this though, but sometimes it's just easier to say it this way rather than explain *why* you say "one of the ties" as the latter leaves an unanswered question.

Comment: Is using *gave* as the past participle of *give* grammatical in your dialect? Because I've never heard of anything but *given*.